# Problem with editing Template Monster .fla file

Tags: templates, flash

I am having the worst luck with this. We bought a template to update our own website (don't have enough time to start our own from scratch!) but when I make simple changes in the Flash CS4 native file and re-export the swf, it doesn't work correctly!

I am wondering if anyone has run across the same problems with a Template Monster Flash website template.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please give us more details by what you mean with "it doesn't work correctly!". Text is the wrong size? Buttons don't work? Entire screen is blank? etc etc

One thing to try is check what version of flash and what version of actionscript you are exporting to, make sure they are the same versions it was designed with. You could also try downloading an older version of Flash and see if that fixes the problem (they all have 30-day trials). And finally, you did pay money for a product, if it's defective, contact the people that sold it to you.

Comment: The swf only plays the intro animation and never gets into the rest of the site. I have Flash 8 and CS4. The template was created in CS3 so maybe that's my problem.

Comment: We bought CS4 not knowing that there would be such a compatibility issue. And I can't afford to buy CS3 and already had a trial so I cannot get another. The support people don't have a clue.

Answer (score 0):

***use flash mx ppl..it's so easy..***